# Why were "skin" and "niggle" slang words meaning to hurry?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

I've read in a book *From Flappers to Rappers: The Study of American Youth Slang* two words used commonly within the same decade 1900-1910 meaning to hurry were "skin" and "niggle". I'm puzzled as to why these words would be selected and used to mean hurry: "Let's skin!" or "Let's niggle!". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a superficial search, my guess is you may not find a logical answer to "why" other than **someone decided to repurpose the word and it caught on**. Sometimes, the meaning gradually changes because enough people simply choose to use (or "misuse") a word.

Your best bet is looking for the earliest instances of the terms with that usage (I haven't found any sources).

*Niggle*, in various dialects, has been given so many disparate definitions that asking "why" may not be the most illuminating question. Some definitions for **niggle** include *cum, castrate, trot slowly, coax out, squeeze out or hand out slyly* and  *possess carnally*.

I was able to trace the "hurry" definition of *niggle* to "[Dialect Notes, Volume 2](http://books.google.com/books?id=3JI0AQAAMAAJ&q=%22niggle%22&dq=%22niggle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zy0WU7-4G8KC2QW5kIDwCA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBA)" printed by the University of Alabama in 1900. I do not know their source, but it provides a time and perhaps geography (the source is not necessarily the American South).

I will update as I find more information. Perhaps an actual reason will appear.

Some possibilities:

- *niggle* meant "to coax or deceive," so after "niggling," one might want to make haste
- *niggle* meant "to scribble" (draw or write hurriedly), so *niggle* could describe doing anything in quick fashion

Comment: Very nice, +1. Could you provide your source for the various definitions of _niggle_? My own five whole minutes of searching did not come up with any.